# median of two sorted arrays of different size

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

i was solving this problem from geeks for geeks http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays-of-different-sizes/  but when i implemented the same code ,then for input 
A[] = {1,2,3}
B[] = {3,6,9,12}
it is giving wrong output as 6 but it should be 3 ,someone please tell me the problem with my code?

```
//code

#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;


float single_median(int arr[],int size)//method to find median in an arr

{
    if(size == 0)
    return -1;

    else if(size%2==0)
    return (arr[size/2] + arr[size/2 -1])/2.0;

    else
    return arr[size/2];
}

float medianOf2(int a,int b)//median of two numbers
{
    return ((a+b)/2.0);
}

int medianOf3(int a,int b,int c)//median of 3 numbers
{
    int maximum = max(a,max(b,c));
    int minimum = min(a,min(b,c));
    return ((a+b+c) - maximum - minimum);
}

int medianOf4(int a, int b,int c,int d)//median of 4 numbers
{
    int maximum = max(a,max(b,max(c,d)));
    int minimum = min(a,min(b,min(c,d)));
    return ((a+b+c+d) - maximum - minimum);
}

int find_median(int A[],int m,int B[],int n)
{
    if(m<n)//here we will keep in mind that A is larger than B else we swap
    return find_median(B,n,A,m);

    if(n==0)//if smaller array has no element just find the median of larger array
    return single_median(A,m);

    if(n==1)//if smaller array has one element
    {
        if(m==1)
        return (A[0]+B[0])/2.0;//if both has one element just return the average

        else if(m&1)//when larger array has odd elements
        return medianOf2(medianOf3(B[0],A[m/2 - 1],A[m/2 + 1]),A[m/2]);

        else//for e
        return medianOf3(B[0],A[m/2],A[m/2 -1]);

    }

    if(n==2)
    {
        if(m==2)
        return medianOf4(A[0],B[0],A[1],B[1]);

        else if(m&1)
        return medianOf3(max(B[0],A[m/2 -1]),min(B[1],A[m/2 +1]),A[m/2]);

        else
        return medianOf4(max(B[0],A[m/2 -2]),min(B[1],A[m/2 +1]),A[m/2],A[m/2 -1]);

    }

    int mid_m = (m-1)/2;
    int mid_n = (n-1)/2;

    if(A[mid_m]<B[mid_n])
        find_median(A + mid_m,m/2 +1 ,B,n - mid_n);
    else
        find_median(A,n/2 +1, B + mid_n, n/2 + 1);


}

int main()
{
    int B[] = {1,2,3};
    int A[] = {3,6,9,12};

    cout<<find_median(A,4,B,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions like "tell me the problem with my code" are not allowed here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: ok sir i will not repeat this,thanks for informing.

Comment: `return ((a+b+c+d) - maximum - minimum);` <-- this line is missing divide by `2.0`, which makes sense, since you're getting 6, but should be 3. fix that line to this: `return ((a+b+c+d) - maximum - minimum) / 2.0;`

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to divide the result by 2.0 in the `medianOf4` function before returning the result as so:

```
int medianOf4(int a, int b,int c,int d)//median of 4 numbers
{
    int maximum = max(a,max(b,max(c,d)));
    int minimum = min(a,min(b,min(c,d)));
    return ((a+b+c+d) - maximum - minimum) / 2.0; # <-- forgot to add "/ 2.0"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @skvatss If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
public double FindMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    if(nums1== null || nums1.Length<1)
        return result(nums2);
    else if(nums2== null || nums2.Length<1)
        return result(nums1);

    int[] merged = new int[nums1.Length + nums2.Length];
    int num1Ind=0;
    int num2Ind=0;
    int currInd = 0;

    while(num1Ind<nums1.Length &&  num2Ind<nums2.Length){
        if(nums1[num1Ind]< nums2[num2Ind])
            merged[currInd++]=nums1[num1Ind++];
        else
            merged[currInd++]=nums2[num2Ind++];
    }

    if(num2Ind<nums2.Length)
        for(int i=num2Ind; i<nums2.Length; i++)
           merged[currInd++]=nums2[i];
    else if(num1Ind<nums1.Length)
        for(int i=num1Ind; i<nums1.Length; i++)
           merged[currInd++]=nums1[i];

    return result(merged);
}

private double result(int[] merged){
    if(merged.Length==1)
        return merged[0];
     if((merged.Length)%2 !=0)
        return (double)merged[merged.Length/2];
     return (double)(merged[merged.Length/2-1] + merged[merged.Length/2])/2;


}
```

}